# Counting restricted ordered rooted trees by the number of leaves and non-leaves

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

I have proved that the number of ordered rooted unlabeled trees on $n+1$ vertices with $j$ leaves is $\dfrac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{j}\binom{n-1}{j}$. I did this by writing a recurrence using that fact that removing a leaf gives either a tree with the same number of leaves and one fewer vertex or a tree with one fewer vertex and one fewer leaf.

I want to "extend" this to count trees with $n+k-1$ vertices, $n-1$ leaves, and the property that no vertex has exactly one child.

I tried setting up a recurrence for this, where when I delete a leaf, I either get a good tree with one fewer leaf and vertex, or I get a bad tree with exactly one vertex with one child, and I can count bad trees by just counting the edges of the bad tree with the vertex deleted and the two edges on it joined into a single edge. However, this fails when the bad vertex is the root, since then it does not have degree $2$, and I can't seem to fix the recurrence to get the correct answer, which is supposed to be $\dfrac{1}{n+k-1}\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}\binom{n-3}{n-k-2}$. Is there a better way to form the recurrence?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a contribution using basic complex variables.

The  species equation  for ordered  rooted trees  where no  vertex has
exactly one child with leaves marked is
$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z}\mathcal{U}
+ \mathcal{Z} \mathfrak{S}_{\ge 2}(\mathcal{T})
\quad\text{or}\quad
\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z}\mathcal{U}
+ \mathcal{Z} \frac{\mathcal{T}^2}{1-\mathcal{T}}.$$

This yields the functional equation for the generating function $T(z)$
$$T(z) = zu + z\frac{T^2(z)}{1-T(z)}$$
or $$z = \frac{T(z)}{u+T^2(z)/(1-T(z))}
= \frac{T(z)(1-T(z))}{T^2(z)+u(1-T(z))}.$$

We seek
$$T_n(u) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} T(z) \; dz.$$
and will compute this by Lagrange inversion.

Put $w=T(z)$ so that
$$dz = 
\left(\frac{1-2w}{w^2+u(1-w)}
-\frac{w(1-w)}{(w^2+u(1-w))^2}(2w-u)\right) dw.$$

to get the two integrals
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w^2+u(1-w))^{n+1}}{w^{n+1}(1-w)^{n+1}} 
\times w\times \frac{1-2w}{w^2+u(1-w)} \; dw.$$
and
$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w^2+u(1-w))^{n+1}}{w^{n+1}(1-w)^{n+1}} 
\times w\times \frac{w(1-w)}{(w^2+u(1-w))^2}(2w-u) \; dw.$$

This simplifies to give four pieces, piece $A_1$ is
(write $1-2w = -w + (1-w)$)
$$- \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w^2+u(1-w))^{n}}{w^{n-1}(1-w)^{n+1}} \; dw$$
and piece $A_2$ is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w^2+u(1-w))^{n}}{w^{n}(1-w)^{n}} \; dw.$$

Piece $B$ is
$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w^2+u(1-w))^{n-1}}{w^{n-1}(1-w)^{n}} (2w-u) \; dw.$$

This gives piece $B_1$
$$-2\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w^2+u(1-w))^{n-1}}{w^{n-2}(1-w)^{n}} \; dw$$
and piece $B_2$
$$u\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(w^2+u(1-w))^{n-1}}{w^{n-1}(1-w)^{n}}\; dw.$$

Recall that the leaves are also  marked with $z$ in addition to $u$ so
that we may have up to $q=n-1$ leaves. Extracting the coefficient from
$A_1$ yields
$$- {n\choose q}\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{w^{2n-2q} (1-w)^q}{w^{n-1}(1-w)^{n+1}} \; dw$$
and piece $A_2$ yields
$${n\choose q}\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{w^{2n-2q} (1-w)^q}{w^{n}(1-w)^{n}} \; dw.$$

This simplifies to
$$-{n\choose q}\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{2q-n-1}(1-w)^{n-q+1}} \; dw
= -{n\choose q} {q-2\choose n-q}$$
and
$${n\choose q}\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{2q-n}(1-w)^{n-q}} \; dw
= {n\choose q} {q-2\choose n-q-1}.$$

Extracting the coefficient from $B_1$ yields
$$-2{n-1\choose q}\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{w^{2n-2q-2} (1-w)^q}{w^{n-2}(1-w)^{n}} \; dw$$
and piece $B_2$ yields
$${n-1\choose q-1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{w^{2n-2q}(1-w)^{q-1}}{w^{n-1}(1-w)^{n}}\; dw.$$

This simplifies to
$$-2{n-1\choose q}\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{2q-n}(1-w)^{n-q}} \; dw
= -2{n-1\choose q} {q-2\choose n-q-1}$$
and piece $B_2$ yields
$${n-1\choose q-1} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{w^{2q-n-1}(1-w)^{n-q+1}}\; dw
= {n-1\choose q-1} {q-2\choose n-q}.$$

Collecting everything we obtain the formula

$${n-1\choose q-1} {q-2\choose n-q}
\left(1-2\frac{n-q}{q}\frac{n-q}{2q-n-1}
+\frac{n}{q}\frac{n-q}{2q-n-1}-\frac{n}{q}\right)$$
which is
$$\frac{1}{2q-n-1} 
\frac{n-q}{q}{n-1\choose q-1} {q-2\choose n-q}$$
or
$$\frac{1}{2q-n-1} 
{n-1\choose q} {q-2\choose n-q}.$$

In the question from the OP we have $n=n'+k'-1$ and $q=n'-1$
which yields
$$\frac{1}{2n'-2-n'-k'+1-1} 
{n'+k'-2\choose n'-1} {n'-1-2\choose k'}$$
or
$$\frac{1}{n'-k'-2} 
{n'+k'-2\choose n'-1} {n'-3 \choose n'-k'-3}$$
which is
$$\frac{1}{k'} {n'+k'-2\choose n'-1} {n'-3 \choose n'-k'-2}$$
which finally yields
$$\frac{1}{n'+k'-1} {n'+k'-1\choose n'-1} {n'-3 \choose n'-k'-2},$$
confirming the result conjectured by the OP.

**Addendum.** The formula 
$$\frac{1}{2q-n-1} 
{n-1\choose q} {q-2\choose n-q}$$

has the problem  that when $n$ is odd  and $q=\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1$ we
get a singularity because $2q-n-1=0$ but this value of $q$ is included
in  the  generating  function.  Therefore   it  is  best  to  do  some
hypergeometric refactoring (same as above), obtaining

$$\frac{1}{2q-n-1} 
{n-1\choose q} \frac{(q-2)!}{(2q-n-2)! (n-q)!}
= {n-1\choose q} \frac{(q-2)!}{(2q-n-1)! (n-q)!}
\\ = \frac{1}{n-q} {n-1\choose q} {q-2\choose n-q-1}.$$

Now because  $q$ ranges from  $\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1$ to $n-1$  we have
that for $n\ge 2$
$$T_n(u) = \sum_{q=\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^{n-1}
\frac{1}{n-q} {n-1\choose q} {q-2\choose n-q-1} u^q.$$

This gives e.g. for $n=8$ the generating function
$$T_8(u) = {u}^{7}+14\,{u}^{6}+21\,{u}^{5}$$
and for $n=9$
$$T_9(u) = {u}^{8}+20\,{u}^{7}+56\,{u}^{6}+14\,{u}^{5}.$$

The  sequence $T_n(1)$  removes  the classification  according to  the
number of leaves and simply counts ordered rooted trees with no vertex
with one child, giving
$$0, 1, 1, 3, 6, 15, 36, 91, 232, 603, 1585, \ldots$$
which is [OEIS A005043](https://oeis.org/A005043)
 where  additional  reference  material  awaits. (This  sequence  would
appear to be one of the more important ones in combinatorics.)

Observe  that for  small $n$  e.g. $n\le  12$ the  generating function
$T_n(u)$  can be  computed with  Maple's **combstruct**  package. This
gives e.g.
$$T_{12}(u) = 
{u}^{11}+44\,{u}^{10}+385\,{u}^{9}+825\,{u}^{8}+330\,{u}^{7}.$$

This is the Maple code.

```
with(combstruct);

gf_cs :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local trees, leaves;

    trees := { T=Union(Prod(Z, U),
                       Prod(Z, Sequence(T, 2<= card))),
               Z=Atom, U=Epsilon };

    leaves :=
    proc(struct)
        if type(struct, function) then
            return add(leaves(op(q, struct)), q=1..nops(struct));
        fi;

        if struct = Z then return 0 fi;
        return 1;
    end;

    add(u^leaves(t), t in allstructs([T, trees], size=n));
end;
```

The command

```
> seq(count([T, trees], size=n), n=1..12);
```

will instantly produce the sequence $T_n(1)$ from above.
Another method to compute the $T_n(u)$ with Maple is to solve the functional equation which is only a quadratic and compute the coefficients of the Taylor series.

**Addendum II.** Another hypergeometric refactoring will produce the formula
$$T_n(u) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{q=\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^{n-1}
{n\choose q} {q-2\choose n-q-1} u^q,$$
also for $n \ge 2,$ which incidentally suggest differentiating the functional equation.

Comment: What exactly is the generating function $T(z)$ counting by? Is it counting by the number of vertices or by the number of leaves? I'm not too familiar with analytic combinatorics, so it's not immediately clear to me.

Comment: The OGF $T(z)$ uses the variable $z$ for nodes (leaves and otherwise) and marks them with the variable $u$ to indicate how many of these are leaves. Therefore the term $u^q z^n$ represents a tree on $n$ nodes of which $q$ are leaves.

Comment: So T(z) is actually an expression in both $z$ and $u$?

Comment: Correct, that is why I write $T_n(u)$ for the coefficients $[z^n] T(z).$

Comment: So the functional equation $T(z)=zu+z\dfrac{T(z)^2}{1-T(z)}$ means that choosing such a tree involves either choosing the tree with one vertex or choosing a root, then partitioning the remaining vertices into at least $2$ parts and putting another such tree on each part?

Comment: That too is correct. Note that the partition is ordered because the tree is ordered.

Comment: Hmm, so is there a way to use this to extract the coefficients directly without using complex analysis? Or maybe I can show that the coefficients I have satisfy the functional equation.

Comment: MSE says to close. You could try proving that the closed form I gave for $T_n(u)$ satisfies the functional equation. Unfortunately this will probably create convolutions of binomial coefficients that in turn require complex variables for evaluation. I don't exclude however that someone manages to do this. There is also the possibility of a combinatorics-only approach without the symbolic method.

Comment: I just saw your 2nd addendum: why do you suggest differentiating the functional equation? And with respect to what variable?